# File download using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, download

I am using Rails to make a small file upload app. For file attachment I am using the wonderful Paperclip but I can't work out how to do downloads.

How would I create a link in my show view, that is passed the file id, for instance that would allow the user to download a file on my server?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the file uploaded is attached to a model, e.g. as an attribute called `avatar`, then you can create a link like:

```
<%= link_to "Download", model.avatar.url(:original, false) %>
```

Replace `avatar` with the name of your attribute.

Comment: Could you give an example of what might replace "whatever" ?  For example I have a DBFiles model ... but there is no method .url for this model...

Comment: The whatever would be your "file", "avatar" or whatever you called the file property on your model. So "aUserElement.avatar.url(:original, false)" for instance.

Comment: what does original:false mean?

Comment: Using parameters of `:original, false` tells Paperclip to send the original-sized file (first parameter) and `false` (second parameter) tells it to _not_ include the timestamp on the URL.

Comment: This generates a link for me, to open the file in browser itself, if possible.
If you want to explicitly download, I had to add an extra HTML attribute of download.
So, my final code was -  
`<%= link_to "Download", model.avatar.url(:original, false), :download => '' %>`. 
Ref - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

Answer (score 1):

Replace whatever by name that are user in your model for paper clip 
if you have

resource_file_name,
resource_file_name,
resource_file_name,

then replace whatever by resource