# Download file using gem Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, paperclip

I want to understand how to download file using Paperclip. I upload file to local storage.

It's Model:

```
class AFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attach,
  :url => "public/attach/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/attach/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach, content_type: "text/plain"
end
```

It's View show.html.erb :

```
<p>
  <strong>AFile:</strong>
  <%= @afile.name_file %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Download', @afile.attach.url(:original, false) %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_afile_path(@afile) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', afiles_path %>
```

I did like this:
[File download using Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016194/file-download-using-paperclip)
but it did not help.

But when i click on the Download, then an error:
**No route matches [GET] "/public/attach/text.txt"**

How to solve this problem? Why file cannot be downloaded by clicking "Download"?

Comment: Have you written a download method?

Comment: @Nithin, No, I did not write a method to download

Comment: try writing one, if it works, post as answer ;)

Comment: If he is placing the files in the public directory he does not need a "download method" - if what you really mean is a route and controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails places the `/public` directory in the servers web root. So a file with the file system path `/public/foo.txt` will be accessible at `http://localhost:3000/foo.txt` - not `http://localhost:3000/public/foo.txt`.

So you need to change `url` option for the attached file:

```
class AFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attach,
  :url => "/attach/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/attach/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach, content_type: "text/plain"
end
```

Comment: PS. The singular form is `attachment` - `attach` is a verb. I would name the class `Attachment` or `Upload` and `has_attached_file :file`. `AFile` is a really poor model name when it comes to pluralization.

Comment: already have good changes! Now i have :url => "/attach/:basename.:extension" and error "no routes..." disappeared! Now, the browser displays the contents of the file. To file downloaded after clicking "Download" I should write a method to download and make changes to routes.rb?

Comment: Yes you would create a route and a controller. Use send_file to send the file as the payload in the response.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me!

Answer (score -1):

My solution to download file is something like :

```
<%= link_to 'Download', @afile.attach.url(:original),
    download: @afile.attach.url(:original)%>
```